# Local form of holomorphic functions near a zero.

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-topology, branch-points

My question is one from complex analysis.Suppose $f(z)$ is a holomorphic function in a neighborhood of $z_0$ and that $f(z_0)=f'(z_0)=0$ and $f''(z_0)\neq 0$ that is,$f$ has a zero of order $2$ i.e. $f(z)=(z-z_0)^2.G(z)$ where $G(z)$ is a holomorphic function which does not vanish at $z_0$.Now I know that $f$ will locally look like the square function $z\mapsto z^2$ ,which is up to some change of coordinates/local charts.But I am unable to find a suitable change of coordinates map that will take $z_0$ to the point $0$ and $F(z)$ under the change of coordinates will look like $z\mapsto z^2$.

*Note:*

Here the power $2$ is nothing special.In general if $f$ has  a zero of order $k$ then locally $f$ looks like $z\mapsto z^k$ and this is true for any $k\in \mathbb N$,the set of positive integers.

It would be very nice if someone helps me by providing some intuition about how to find that map out?

Comment: a translation takes you to zero so assume $z_0=0$ and then $w=z \sqrt G$ with a choice of $\sqrt G(0)$ to fix the local branch gives you the change of variable on a small enough disc around zero at least in making $f(w)=cw^2, c \ne 0$ etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$ G(z_0) = \frac{1}{2}f''(z_0)\neq 0$
by assumption.
Let $U$ be a simply connected open neighbourhood of $G(z_0)$, and let
$\log \colon U \to \Bbb C$
be a holomorphic determination of the logarithm.
On a small enough disk $D(z_0,\varepsilon)$, $G$ takes values in $U$.
On this disk, write
$f(z) = \varphi(z)^2$
with
$\varphi(z) = (z-z_0)\exp\left(\frac{1}{2}\ln G(z)\right)$.
Then $\varphi$ is holomorphic on $D(z_0,\varepsilon)$, and straightforward computations show that
$(\varphi'(z_0))^2 = G(z_0) \neq 0$.
Therefore, $\varphi'(z_0)\neq 0$.
By the holomorphic inverse function Theorem, there is $r\in(0,\varepsilon)$ such that $\varphi \colon D(z_0,r) \to V=\varphi(D(z_0,r))$ is a biholomorphism.
Note that $0 = \varphi(z_0) \in V$.
Hence,
$f\circ \varphi^{-1} \colon V \to \Bbb C$
is defined on a neighbourhood of $0$ and has the expression
$f(\varphi^{-1}(w)) = \left(\varphi\left(\varphi^{-1}(w)\right)\right)^2 = \omega^2$.

The exact same method works for any $k$.